# 'Incorrect Type of Metal Texture' - Fixed by Disabling Metal API Validation. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, textures, rendering, metal

I am loading a 3D object into ARKit on a `MTLDevice` with textures programmatically (.dae + .jpg) and it has transparency. However, when I set the `objectNode.transparency` property to anything other than 1.0 (the default float value), then I receive the following error and the app crashes: `Function(commonprofile_frag): incorrect type of texture (MTLTextureTypeCubeArray) bound at texture binding at index 7 (expect MTLTextureTypeCube) for u_radianceTexture[0].'` I have looked at Apple's documentation and developer blog and it seemed to be an error from an earlier Xcode version - however I am running the latest full release - 10.1 (10B61).

It turns out I actually solved this by popping into the Product>Scheme>EditScheme>Options tab and disabling "Metal API Validation". Everything seems to be working properly as of now... does this expose to scrutiny from Apple and/or possible errors? Why did this work as a solution?

Comment: What's the type of the texture that is marked with [[texture(7)]] in the shaders? Disabling API validation doesn't fix it, it just results in no warnings or errors being generated and an undefined behavior.

Comment: @Spo1ler Yet unable to check shaders as app aborts immediately upon attempting to load (cannot perform GPU Capture). Interestingly, disabling environmentalTexturing also seems to do the trick. In one Apple thread, seems was a bug in an early beta; will update and check - otherwise will keep disabled validation as have yet to see any strange behavior otherwise.